# Convert List to Int with Python

Tags: python, xpath, int, type-conversion

I've reviewed a few questions already here to do this, but with no luck.

I'm trying to convert the variable `phone_numbers` from a `list` to a `int` in order to properly insert it into a database column INT(10) e.g. 8881112222

I currently have:

```
phone_numbers = toasted_tree.xpath('//b/text()')
#convert phone number 888-111-2222 to 8881112222
for phone_number in phone_numbers:
    phone_number = phone_number.replace('-', '').replace('','')
    print phone_number
```

This outputs numbers without a `-` just fine.

The problem is, I want these values to be a `int` form and I still believe their in `list` form (just without dashes, How can I do this?

Comment: What is the point of `.replace('','')`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since `xpath()` returns a list of strings and you apply [`.replace()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.replace) - `phone_number` is definitely a string, you can convert it to `int` using [`int()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#int):

```
phone_number = int(phone_number)
```

In case there is only one item returned by the `xpath()` call, just get the first element:

```
phone_number = toasted_tree.xpath('//b/text()')[0]
phone_number = int(phone_number.replace('-', ''))
```

Comment: Great thoroughness here. Thanks a lot @alecxe !